# Not able to locate element in Selenium tried xpath,name,id,css selector

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I have tried using the name, id, xpath. However I get the same error in Eclipse that it is not able to locate the element.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();  
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://accenturenordicspov.service-now.com/navpage.do");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("John");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input[1]")).sendKeys("A***");
driver.findElement(By.id("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/button")).click();
```

Comment: can you please share that HTML code please?

Comment: Have you tried FirePath extention for Firefox browser? If not try it. As i see from the link, all ements you are looking for, have an ID, so use it.
.//*[@id='user_name']  - for username (from here i thing you've got the idea)

Comment: i am using firebug extension for firefox...driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user_name']")).sendKeys("John"); is also not working out for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be in different frame. Kindly check for the frame or iframe tag is parent of the box you are going to interact.
If yeas then You have to switch to that frame then only You can interact.

Comment: Gave you an upvote. I didn't notice that the form was in an `iframe`. Good work! :)

Comment: Yes it was a frame issue....i wrote the code to change the frame and then input the elements.... its working now...thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

According to the link you've given, the form is in an `iframe`. Hence, you need to switch to the frame and then fill the form. You should try this:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("gsft_main")
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user_name']").sendKeys("John");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user_password']").sendKeys("A***");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='sysverb_login']").click();
```

Comment: OP , please take a look at this tutorial: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ . and you will be able to use xPath properly.

Comment: @Jason- ur script is not working,....! still giving the same error. not able to locate the element.

Comment: @JohnWick - I've update my answer. I didn't notice that the form was in an `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

It first needs to move to that frame and then input the elements. Above code will work if just put this piece of code before inputting the elements:

```
String x="gsft_main";
driver.switchTo().frame(x);
```

Comment: I think you should mark dinesh's answer with a green tick instead of adding your own answer.

Comment: okay did that i am not much familiar with stack recently signed up....thanks for guidance.

Comment: Oh okay. Anyways, Welcome to SO! :)